# Creating custom DTO class results in duplicate JSON properties

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm creating a net core game using Entity Framework. Based on suggestions I found on here, I'm trying to create DTO classes that are a mesh of data from different tables in my database.

Here is once such DTO class I created. It's a custom class based on two different tables in the database. The first 3 properties are from my dungeon table and the last 3 are from my dungeonRoom table:

```
public partial class GameDungeon
{
    public string DungeonId { get; set; }
    public string DungeonName { get; set; }
    public string StartRoom { get; set; }
    public string RoomId { get; set; }
    public string RoomText { get; set; }
    public string TreasureId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the API controller I am using to get this data:

```
        [HttpGet("GetDungeonAndRoomData/{dungeonId}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<GameDungeon>>> GetDungeonAndRoomData(Guid dungeonID)
    {
        var vpSimDungeon = await (from c in _context.DungeonList
                               join n in _context.RoomList on c.DungeonId equals n.DungeonId
                               where c.DungeonId == dungeonID
                               select new GameDungeon
                               {
                                   DungeonId = c.DungeonId,
                                   DungeonName = c.DungeonName,
                                   StartRoom = c.StartRoom,
                                   RoomId = n.RoomId,
                                   RoomText = n.RoomText,
                                   TreasureId = n.TreasureId
                               }).ToListAsync();
        return vpSimDungeon;
    }
```

I am getting no errors, but I am getting duplicate data.

Here is an example. You can see that dungeonId, dungeonName, and startRoom are being repeated.

I think I know why, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
[
            { 
                "dungeonId" : "293hf938",
                "dungeonName" : "Dungeon of Dread",
                "startRoom" : "bjgh39811ffr",
                "roomId" : "fgf4h635j",
                "roomText" : "A big empty room",
                "treasureId" : "12a"
            },
            { 
                "dungeonId" : "293hf938",
                "dungeonName" : "Dungeon of Dread",
                "startRoom" : "bjgh39811ffr",   
                "roomId" : "kyqv56904fd",
                "roomText" : "A large room with a giant spider web in the middle",
                "treasureId" : "18d"                
            },
            { 
                "dungeonId" : "293hf938",
                "dungeonName" : "Dungeon of Dread",
                "startRoom" : "bjgh39811ffr",           
                "roomId" : "bjgh39811ffr",
                "roomText" : "The dungeon opens up to this canvernous, moss-covered room",
                "treasureId" : "8a"
            }

        ]
```

Is there a way to get the JSON to only output the dungeon data once?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but you need to realize that the relationship between dungeons and rooms is a 0-Many. So, because you are joining 3 rooms to 1 dungeon, you are getting all three rooms back, joined with the dungeon. To only get 1 dungeon and maintain the join, you will have to use an array of rooms in your GameDungeon object. The room object would include the roomId, roomText and treasureId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a DTO class doesn't mean you have to flatten your data; it just means you should be using a class other than your actual entity class to represent the data. You still want to (for the most part at least) mirror the hierarchy that exists in your entity classes in your DTOs. In other words, you should also have a DTO for `Room`, and then you should have a list of rooms tied to the dungeon.

```
var dungeon = await _context.DungeonList
    .Select(c => new GameDungeon
    {
        DungeonId = c.DungeonId,
        DungeonName = c.DungeonName,
        StartRoom = c.StartRoom,
        Rooms = c.Rooms.Select(n => new GameDungeonRoom
        {
            RoomId = n.RoomId,
            RoomText = n.RoomText,
            TreasureId = n.TreasureId
        })
    }).SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.DungeonId == dungeonID);
```

Comment: Thanks , so in your example, GameDungeon is a DTO class and GameDungeonRoom is a DTO class as well? In the GameDungeon class, would 'Rooms' be an array?

Comment: Yes, though it's more apt to call it an "enumerable", since that's what `Select` returns. Once serialized to JSON, it would be a JavaScript array, if that's what you meant.

Comment: I was wondering how to make it in my GameDungeon.cs class.  I'm guessing like this? public virtual ICollection<GameDungeonRoom> Rooms { get; set; }

Comment: Not virtual and List or IEnumerable instead of ICollection, but yes.